# pygame.draw.rect can't handle operations between a value in a tuple and an integer, but any other function can

Tags: python, pygame

With my program, I'm trying to locate the coordinates of a Rect that contains text that will be displayed on the screen. When I try using pygame.draw.rect and subtract a number from one of the Rect's coordinates, I get an error that says that I can't perform operations on tuples. However, when I tried printing this, it showed up without any errors. The code might do a better job at explaining

```
while True:
        ###
        text1, text1_rect = gameFont.render("Start", (255,255,255))
        text2, text2_rect = gameFont.render("Continue", (255,255,255))
        text3, text3_rect = gameFont.render("Quit", (255,255,255))
        text1_rect.center = (WIDTH/2, 400)
        text2_rect.topleft = (text1_rect.x,text1_rect.y + 50)
        text3_rect.topleft = (text1_rect.x,text2_rect.y + 50)
        ###
        screen.fill(BLACK) # Scroll right to read message --> 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (text1_rect.x - 10,text1_rect.center-3,6,6)) # When I say text1_rect.x - 10, it raises an error. If I put this into print(), it returns a value without the error.
        screen.blit(text1, text1_rect)
        screen.blit(text2, text2_rect)
        screen.blit(text3, text3_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
```

This line is what I was talking about:

```
text1_rect.x - 10
```

When put into pygame.draw.rect, error. But when I print it, no error. What on Earth is going on?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure that text1_rect.x is an integer, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are placing the arguments into a tuple. Try using a list instead.
Also I'm pretty sure you need to add another argument for line thickness.

Replace

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (text1_rect.x - 10,text1_rect.center-3,6,6))
```

With

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [text1_rect.x - 10,text1_rect.center-3,6,6], 2)
```

Comment: The function takes multiple arguments. Specific arguments must have a certain type and the 3rd argument was supposed to be a list, not a tuple which you made.

Comment: I do not think the code will work as you are trying to subtract a integer from a tuple `text1_rect.center-3`

Comment: But the third argument is a Rect and aren't Rects tuples?

Comment: No, the third argument is a set of arguments [x, y, width, height] that define the position and size of the rectangle.